# Paginating through comments via YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, postman, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to scrape all comments of an YouTube video. The comment API is paginated and limited to 100 items per page.

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2Creplies%22%5D%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22_VB39Jo8mAQ%22%7D`.

If the page has the attribute `nextPageToken`, there are more comments on that page. If not, you have reached the last page. I can confirm this with this request to a video that conveniently has 97 comments:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId=WZePccmYHQ8&key=*********************&maxResults=100`

[image: Screenshot: Requesting 100 comments]

So what I'm trying is: I'm requesting the comments with `...&maxResults=90`, this gives me a `nextPageToken`:

[image: Screenshot: Requesting 90 comments]

Now I take the `nextPageToken`, and add it as a `pageToken` to another request:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId=WZePccmYHQ8&key=*********************&maxResults=90&PageToken=QURTSl9pM3JDSTJYZzVjZFlDRUhJXzh3aHlpamdjN25ycTl5UkpBTU9GQVRRMFllVU5EbWVyU3Zwa0hRdWxVaGVqVWhlWUxqaUVCelh5Yw==`

I would expect to see:

```json
    "pageInfo": {
            "totalResults": 7,
            "resultsPerPage": 90
    },
```

But I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot: 90/90 again]

Can anyone tell me why? I am very new to this, as you can tell.

Comment: I always ignore `totalResults`. It's unreliable. The `items` array resulted upon the last API call above should have 7 elements, if indeed your video has 97 top-level comments. (I checked: the video `WZePccmYHQ8` has indeed 97 top-level comments.)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. Unfortunately, i get the exact same comments in both requests. Maybe i should have been clearer. The responses looke exactly the same, except that the NextPageToken are newly generated.

Comment: Also I checked the two API calls and got 90 and respectively 7 top-level entries in the two JSON responses. Surprisingly, the second `totalResults` of mine is `7`.

Comment: Replace `PageToken` with `pageToken`. Notice the change in the first char's case. I checked this too and am confirming that this is the error (am getting exactly the same JSON when using `PageToken`, modulo the `nextPageToken` property.)

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you. I didn't know that the case mattered in URL-Parameters. ( For some reason i can't mark your answer as the solution)

Comment: It's the API back-end that is case-sensitive.

Comment: On this forum it's accustomed that errors caused by *typos* to not be considered *real issues*. That's why I did not posted an actual answer to your question, but only a comment under your post.